# How do I assign different colors to different sections I've created in p5.js via the map function?

Tags: p5.js

How should I assign different transparent colors to each section created by the map function? Each slice proportionally represents the amount of money the US government spends for each category relative to its total spending. I've tried using the setAlpha() function to make the color transparent, but it made a gradient rather than making it transparent all throughout. More than this, I'm struggling to make changes to each section without altering the entire rectangle.

[image: screenshot of current output]

This is my code right now:

```js
function setup() {
  createCanvas(800, 400);
  dollar=loadImage('https://media.istockphoto.com/id/1198332549/vector/american-usd-dollar-bill-outline-isolated-on-white-background.jpg?s=1024x1024&w=is&k=20&c=HLVlJ9Ak63IIK2ddS-I-_gr_rHKH8OEFlAGNVNMUhQw=')
  spending = [
    {name: "Social Security",
    billions: 1220},
    {name: "Health Care",
    billions: 914},
    {name: "Income Security",
    billions: 865},
    {name: "National Defense",
    billions: 767},
    {name: "Medicare",
    billions: 755},
    {name: "Education",
    billions: 677},
    {name: "Interest",
    billions: 475},
    {name: "Veteran Benefits",
    billions: 274},
    {name: "Transportation",
    billions: 132},
    {name: "Government",
    billions: 129},
    {name: "Other",
    billions: 65}
  ];
}

function draw() {
  background(255);
  image(dollar,80,-100)
  dollar.resize(600,0)
  for (let i=0;i<spending.length;i++){
    fill(255,0,0,10)
    let sectionwidth = map(spending[i].billions,0,6273,0,2470)
    rect(140,97,sectionwidth,205)
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.6.0/p5.js"></script>
```

I tried setting the alpha value, but that only resulted in a gradient.
I also tried adjusting the value of "i" in my conditional statement so that p5.js would generate each section separately, but it resulted in rectangles with colors split down the middle.

[image]

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to accomplish. If you make the fill color "transparent all throughout" then it wouldn't be visible at all would it. It looks like the gradient in your code example is happening because the "sections" all overlap to some extent since they have the same X position. Is the second screenshot intended to be an example of what you want or another iteration that isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues here:

1. Viewing colors on top of the dollar bill
2. Viewing colors on top of each other
3. Not mapping numbers properly

For issue #1, we can draw the dollar bill image on top of the colors, and essentially get rid of the background by changing the [`blendMode`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/blendMode) to `MULTIPLY`.

Your rectangles are stacked on top of each other with the largest on the bottom and the smallest on the top.  They all have the same left edge which is the edge of the dollar bill.  If they have transparency then you will be able to see the color underneath it.  If they are all solid colors then the stacking is not inherently a problem.

But the widths are not correct.  Which brings us to issue #3.

You are mapping the input `billions` number from a range of 0-6273 to a range of 0-2470.  Where do those numbers come from and what do they mean?  What you want to be doing is mapping from the input range of your budget to the output range which is the pixels on the dollar bill image.

I calculated the total and it is `6273` so that's fine.  But what the heck is an output of `2470` doing here when the image is less than `600`px wide?  It looks like `2470` is an arbitrary number you've found that causes the bill to fill up in spite of the unintentional overlapping of the rectangles. If each rectangle is placed side-by-side then the difference between the start and end of the output range should be the width of bill portion of the image.

```
// Map the value from dollars in the budget to pixels on the image.
let sectionWidth = map(spending[i].billions, 0, total, 0, billWidth);
```

Each rectangle starts where the previous one ended.  As we iterate through the sections, I'm updating a `previousEndX` variable to keep track of the current start position.

[image]

```js
function preload() {
  dollar = loadImage(
    "https://media.istockphoto.com/id/1198332549/vector/american-usd-dollar-bill-outline-isolated-on-white-background.jpg?s=1024x1024&w=is&k=20&c=HLVlJ9Ak63IIK2ddS-I-_gr_rHKH8OEFlAGNVNMUhQw="
  );
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(800, 400);
  spending = [
    { name: "Social Security", billions: 1220 },
    { name: "Health Care", billions: 914 },
    { name: "Income Security", billions: 865 },
    { name: "National Defense", billions: 767 },
    { name: "Medicare", billions: 755 },
    { name: "Education", billions: 677 },
    { name: "Interest", billions: 475 },
    { name: "Veteran Benefits", billions: 274 },
    { name: "Transportation", billions: 132 },
    { name: "Government", billions: 129 },
    { name: "Other", billions: 65 },
  ];
}

function draw() {
  // Storing these as variables for clarity.
  let billLeft = 140;
  let billTop = 97;
  let billHeight = 205;
  let billWidth = 475; // approximate
  let total = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < spending.length; i++) {
    total = total + spending[i].billions;
  }
  // This is a variable that we will update, representing where the last rectangle stopped.
  let previousEndX = billLeft;
  // The actual drawing part begins here.
  background(255);
  for (let i = 0; i < spending.length; i++) {
    // I'm picking a random color, but you'll probably want to chose your actual colors.
    colorMode(HSL);
    let sectionColor = color(random(0, 360), random(50, 100), random(50, 90));
    fill(sectionColor);
    // Map the value from dollars in the budget to pixels on the image.
    let sectionWidth = map(spending[i].billions, 0, total, 0, billWidth);
    rect(previousEndX, billTop, sectionWidth, billHeight);
    // Start the next rectangle where we left off.
    previousEndX = previousEndX + sectionWidth;
  }
  blendMode(MULTIPLY);
  dollar.resize(600, 0);
  image(dollar, 80, -100);
  noLoop();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.6.0/p5.js"></script>
```